# Extracting Specific Text From value from a nested dictionaries with python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have the following data structure, which I need to extract the word with **[ft,mi,FT,MI]** of the **state key** and stored in a new key called **distance**.

**Reproducible Example of my data**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1243,
        "class1": [
            {"count":5,
                "state": "Arizona 4.47ft"
            },
            {
                "state": "Georgia 1023mi"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 12438,
        "class1": [
            {"count":2,
                "state": "Newyork 2022 NY 74.6 FT"
            },
            {
                "state": "Indiana 747MI(In)"
            },
            {"count":2,
                "state": "Florida 453mi FL"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

A mini exp of the expected output:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1243,
        "class1": [
            {"count":5,
                "state": "Arizona 4.47ft",
                "distance":"4.47ft"
            },
            {
                "state": "Georgia 1023 mi",
                "distance":"1023 mi"
            }
        ]
    }]
```

The logic that i have build:

```
   for a in df['state']:
    for k in a:
        if "state" in k:
            m = ["ft","mi","FT","MI"]
            df['distance']=df['state'].str.extract(r'(\S+\s?(?:%s))\b' % '|'.join(m))
```

Thank you for your time and have a great day !

Comment: And you post your solution here .... why?

Comment: The code is not working @PatrickArtner im looking for help

Comment: SO comment sections is not the correct place to play 20 questions. Add all informations that are needed to your post. [edit] it. Describe _what_ is not working.  We do not have your dataframe we can not use the code as is.  Is the dataframe important? guess no - you could as well post a simple dictionary?  [mre] and [ask] are good pointers what to do to your question to make it answerable.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I added the structure of the dictionary . and i didnt use the comment sections to play 20 questions

Comment: We would need to play 20 questions to get you to: post a [mre]. tell us what your code does but does not to correctly, explain why nothing of the dictionary with id 12438 is in your expected output, explain what should be outputted for "Newyork 2022 NY 74.6 FT" - your posted code currently does not run, there are no imports, your df is not created etc.

Answer (score -1):

Please see the code which creates "distance" and gets the value from regex pattern  " (.*)".

```
import re

pattern = " (.*)"

for a in data:
    for k in a:
        #print(k)
        if "class" in k:
            #print(a[k])
            for l in a[k]:
                #print(l)
                m = re.findall(pattern, l['state'])
                l['distance'] = m[0]
                #print(l)
    print(a)
```

The output:

[image]

You may edit the regex pattern if it does not give proper data.